# Resolving file descriptor to file name / file path

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I am currently developing a simple kernel module that can steal system calls such as `open`, `read`, `write` and replace them with a simple function which logs the files being opened, read, written, into a file and return the original system calls.

My query is, I am able to get the File Descriptor in `read` and `write` system calls, but I am not able to understand how to obtain file name using the same.

Currently I am able to access the file structure associated with given FD using following code:

```c
struct file *file;
file = fcheck(fd);
```

This file structure has two important entities in it, which are of my concern I believe:

1. `f_path`
2. `f_inode`

Can anybody help me get `dentry` or `inode` or the path name associated with this fd using the file structure associated with it?
Is my approach correct? Or do I need to do something different?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and my kernel version is 3.19.0-25-generic, for the kernel module development.

Answer (score 1):

`.f_inode` is actually an inode.

`.f_path->dentry` is a dentry.

Traversing this dentry via `->d_parent` link, until `f_path.mnt.mnt_root` dentry will be touched, and collecting `dentry->d_name` components, will construct the file's path, relative to the mount point. This is done, e.g., with [d_path](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/dcache.c?v=3.19#L2939), but in more carefull way.

Instead of `fcheck(fd)`, which should be used inside RCU read section, you can also use `fget(fd)`, which should be paired with `fput()`.

Comment: Apologies for not confirming back in time, your approach indeed helped me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is completely incorrect - see http://www.watson.org/~robert/2007woot/

Linux already has a reliable mechanism for doing this thing (audit). If you want to implement it anyway (for fun I presume), you want to place your hooks roughly where audit is doing that. Chances are LSM hooks are in appropriate places, have not checked.